# Getting PyCharm to recognize Anaconda's SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, pycharm, anaconda

I need to use the SciPy libraries inside the PyCharm IDE (on a Mac OSX Lion machine). The SciPy website writes that the simplest installation method for Mac users is to install Anaconda (or an equivalent distro). I used the Anaconda installer, and it created an anaconda directory in my home folder, where I find a `lib/python2.7/site-packages` directory with the required packages. However, PyCharm is not aware of all this and the SciPy import statements remain unresolved.

My question is then how to make PyCharm work with Anaconda?

Comment: Did you run the installation correctly? Did you say 'yes' when it asked you if it can modify `.bashrc`?

Comment: @Rohit In OSX it's .bash_profile, but yes, the installer changed it (added anaconda/bin to the PATH variable).

Comment: Yes. Sorry. That is useful only for the built-in interpreter.

Comment: I'm sure you've looked at this, but nevertheless, http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: @Rohit your link explains the procedure of adding individual packages, but it also pointed me toward a workaround to use Anaconda: navigate to preferences-->Project Interpreter-->Python Interpreters and then in the lower pane choose Paths and add anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages. It seems to be working for now (at least for SciPy), but if anyone knows of a more formal method, add an answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'm still coming to terms with the Python ecosystem and PyCharm, so take the following with a grain of salt, but after [reading up a bit](http://mirnazim.org/writings/python-ecosystem-introduction/), I thought I'd write a detailed explanation.

During installation, Anaconda changes the default Python interpreter to ~/anaconda/bin/python. This interpreter is configured with a `sys.path` that defaults to the libraries in ~/anaconda/lib . Package managers like python's pip use the interpreter that's running them to determine the path in which to install packages, so after Anaconda is installed, all packages installed via pip or other methods will be placed somewhere inside ~/anaconda/lib. i.e. even without using something like virtualenv, every Python interpreter has its own ecosystem and running pip with different interpreters will install packages into different directories.

PyCharm handles all this in the `Project Settings-->Project Interpreter-->Python Interpreters` screen. To make PyCharm aware of the Anaconda distribution, you need to add the Anaconda python interpreter to the  `Project Interpreter-->Python Interpreters` list and make it the default for the project. PyCharm will then locate all packages installed in Anaconda's interpreter ecosystem (~/anaconda/lib) and list them under `packages` in the lower pane. It will also prompt you to install setup_tools and pip for that interpreter, and once you do that you'll be able to use the `install` button in the lower pane to add more packages to the Anaconda ecosystem.

Once you've added the Anaconda interpreter, you can also use the virtualenv button from the toolbar on the upper pane to create a virtualenv that inherits from the Anaconda interpreter's environment. That way you can install new packages in a way that would not affect the global Anaconda distribution.

Comment: How do you get the virtualenv to inherit from Anaconda?

Comment: Pycharm just goes nuts and has to be forcibly shutdown if you start a jupyter notebook. It can't find the notebook url.
I also couldn't find this virtualenv toolbar. I am using the paid version (but I do Java mostly so not a total loss)