# Using (Ana)conda within PyCharm

Tags: python, virtualenv, pycharm, anaconda, conda

I've got Pycharm 4 running on my Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) machine.  In addition to the system python, I've also got Anaconda installed.  Getting the two to play nicely together seems to be a bit of a problem... PyCharm provides some interesting integration for `virtualenv`s and `pip`, but the Anaconda Python distribution seems to prefer using its own `conda` tool for both activities.

Is there a relatively simple/painless way to be able to use `conda` in conjunction with PyCharm?  Not just as an alternative interpreter i.e. point PyCharm at the Anaconda Python binary for a project interpreter, but to be able to create, source/activate and deactivate virtual envs, add/remove packages in those virtual envs, etc.

Or am I going to have to choose between using Anaconda (and having a more recent and up-to-date python than may come with the system), and being able to use PyCharm's features to their fullest extent?

Comment: This may answer at least part of your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/19025207/161801

Comment: Not really... getting PyCharm to see/use the Anaconda Python interpreter, or an interpreter from a virtualenv created using `conda`, is not a problem.  Getting PyCharm to use `conda` to manage or recognize packages or virutalenvs created using `conda`, is.

Comment: I see. I don't think there is a way yet, but you can vote on the feature here http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-13698

Comment: I had problems in getting PyCharm to find installed packages after starting to use Conda, on an Ubuntu (14.04 and later 16.04) with PyCharm 4.5. The problem seems to be that if I have open projects in PyCharm that use a normal `virtualenv`, then the open projects with Conda won't find installed packages. If I close the projects that do not use Conda, then the Conda projects find the packages as they should.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I know it's late, but I thought it would be nice to clarify things: PyCharm and Conda *and pip* work well together.

### The short answer

Just manage Conda **from the command line**. PyCharm will automatically notice changes once they happen, just like it does with **pip**.

### The long answer

Create a new Conda environment:

`conda create --name foo pandas bokeh`

This environment lives under `conda_root/envs/foo`. Your python interpreter is `conda_root/envs/foo/bin/pythonX.X` and your all your site-packages are in `conda_root/envs/foo/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages`. This is same directory structure as in a pip virtual environement. PyCharm sees no difference.

Now to activate your new environment from PyCharm go to *file > settings > project > interpreter*, select *Add local* in the project interpreter field (the little gear wheel) and hunt down your python interpreter. Congratulations! You now have a Conda environment with pandas and bokeh!

Now install more packages:

`conda install scikit-learn`

OK... go back to your interpreter in settings. Magically, PyCharm now sees scikit-learn!

And **the reverse is also true**, i.e. when you pip install another package in PyCharm, Conda will automatically notice. Say you've installed requests. Now list the Conda packages in your current environment:

`conda list`

The list now includes requests and Conda has correctly detected (3rd column) that it was installed with pip.

### Conclusion

This is definitely good news for people like myself who are trying to get away from the pip/virtualenv installation problems when packages are not pure python.

**NB:** I run PyCharm pro edition 4.5.3 on Linux. For Windows users, replace *in command line* with *in the GUI* (and forward slashes with backslashes). There's no reason it shouldn't work for you too.

**EDIT:** PyCharm5 is out with Conda support! In the community edition too.

Comment: sorry but I really can't help with windows. I never use it and  I'm not knowledgeable.

Comment: pycharm will mistakenly think you didn't install any package if you write them in requirements.txt even when they are installed into the right path "~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages", and the program is runnable when you click run

Comment: This answer was most useful in adding some confidence for me because it can be confusing for people like me coming from text editors. I have the pro edition as well and I am happy to know its more helpful that the bass ackward thing I had to deal with on windows since 2006. I also recommend looking at the answer from @Piotr-czapla for the conda environment. I totally avoid Windows CMD prompt when I can. It was trendy in 1998

Comment: TLDR; On Windows your local python for environment is in `conda_root/envs/foo/python.exe`

Comment: There is still an issue with conda envs in PyCharm. Some envs require additional paths, example is cvxopt package, which requires the addtitional path "C:\Anaconda3\envs\foo\Library\mingw-w64\bin". Using the Anacoda prompt and activating the environment there properly sets up the path and all works fine. However the procedure described above does not take care of it, it is too simplistic. Does somebody have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: What if you don't have an executable (`python.exe`) inside your environment folder?

Comment: @information_interchange See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43152007/832230).

Comment: Thanks, yeah I figured that out a while back haha. Somewhat confusing why they would choose to implement it that way (new environment doesn't actually get created if you don't pass in packages to install in it)

Answer (score 21):

Change the project interpreter to `~/anaconda2/python/bin` by going to `File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter`. Also update the run configuration to use the project default Python interpreter via `Run -> Edit Configurations`. This makes [`PyCharm`](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) use [`Anaconda`](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) instead of the default Python interpreter under `usr/bin/python27`.

Answer (score 12):

as per @cyberbikepunk answer pycharm supports Anaconda since pycharm5!

Have a look how easy is to add an environment:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Continuum Analytics now provides instructions on how to setup Anaconda with various IDEs including Pycharm [here](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/ide_integration#pycharm).  However, with Pycharm 5.0.1 running on Unbuntu 15.10 Project Interpreter settings were found via the File | Settings and then under the Project branch of the treeview on the Settings dialog.

Answer (score -1):

this might be repetitive.
I was trying to use pycharm to run flask - had anaconda 3, pycharm 2019.1.1 and windows 10. Created a new conda environment - it threw errors.
Followed these steps -

1. Used the cmd to install python and flask after creating environment as suggested above.
2. Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54175042/python-3-7-anaconda-environment-import-ssl-dll-load-fail-error) answer.
3. As suggested above, went to Run -> Edit Configurations and changed the environment there as well as in (2).

Obviously kept the correct python interpreter (the one in the environment) everywhere.