# What is the difference between Anaconda and Pycharm?

Tags: python, user-interface, pycharm, anaconda

I currently have Pycharm 5.0.4 right now and my teacher wants me to change to Anaconda.

> Do different GUIs actually affect your programming?
>
> What are libraries and what causes one GUI to be more advanced than another?
>
> How does the Kernel change the way the user interfaces with the code?

---

I am a beginner at python and I'm not sure if Pycharm is best for me... For beginners is Pycharm still the best?

Comment: AFAIK PyCharm is an IDE and Anaconda is different Python distro. They aren't mutually exclusive

Comment: How to set up PyCharm to use Anaconda: https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/ide_integration

Comment: PyCharm looks like a good editor. I've never used it (I use an IDE that is for multiple programming languages), but looking at PyCharm, it has a lot of great features for helping you write and debug Python code. It's definitely a good tool for both beginner and professional Python coders. The features in PyCharm may seem overwhelming at first, but as you learn to use those features, they will become your best friend.

Comment: I don't actually know how to use some of the features, I saw little help things that pop up, but I never knew what they were for....

Comment: Do read the tips that PyCharm shows on starting and try them out while the tip window is open. That's the best way to learn most of the highly useful features of PyCharm

Answer (score 23, accepted):

PyCharm is a IDE, anaconda is a set of libraries (a distribution). The good news is that pyCharm supports anoconda. Below is some documentation I pulled from the Wayback Machine (for some reason Anaconda removed their documentation on integrating with Pycharm). If any part of this is outdated, please let me know so I can update it.

---

Use PyCharm’s Preferences to set it to use Anaconda. There are multiple methods to access the Preferences Window, including selecting Preferences within the PyCharm file menu or by clicking the Preferences icon in the top icon bar.

[image] [image]

After the Preferences window is open, navigate to Project Interpreter -> Python Interpreters. Click on the + sign to add Anaconda to the Python Interpreters list.

[image]

If the Anaconda Python path is not listed, select Local... and navigate to the directory in which you installed Anaconda Python. Typically this directory is `~/anaconda/bin/python`.

After you have added Anaconda, you will see it displayed in the list of Python Interpreters, along with the other packages that were installed with it. Click OK. The PyCharm IDE is now set up to use Anaconda.

[image]
MORE INFO: [Configuring available packages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/available-packages.html) and [configuring Anaconda environment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html).

---

See also [Using (Ana)conda within PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390961/using-anaconda-within-pycharm#31937300).

Comment: PyCharm is not a "GUI", PyCharm is an IDE.

Comment: I've fixed my post. Sorry, I was thinking of an IDE in my head, but I wrote GUI.

Comment: "this documentation" does not exist

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this Pedro77. I've updated my answer to include the documentation that used to be at that link.

Answer (score 5):

They can't be compared. In fact, Anaconda is not an IDE, Anaconda is a Python distribution, according to their [website](https://www.continuum.io/downloads):

> Anaconda is a completely free Python distribution (including for commercial use and redistribution). It includes more than 400 of the most popular Python packages for science, math, engineering, and data analysis. See the packages included with Anaconda and the Anaconda changelog.

Actually, you can even use Anaconda with PyCharm, [according to the PyCharm website](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/):

> PyCharm integrates with IPython Notebook, has an interactive Python
>   console, and supports Anaconda as well as multiple scientific packages
>   including Matplotlib and NumPy.