# Anaconda is not creating full environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

[image]

I'm trying to create a conda environment using git-bash and win10. I ran:

```
$ conda create --name my_env
```

The result looks like the screenshot above.

Looking at other environments , I can see they normally look like:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @BlackBear one problem is that if I want to use the environment in PyCharm I need to select a python executable. This will not work with the barebones environment.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

To create the environment with the Python executable, use one of:

```
conda create --name my_env python  # latest available python version
conda create --name my_env python=3.7  # specific python version
```

Without specifying packages, i.e. `python` as above, conda just doesn't install anything at all in `my_env` environment.

---

You can alternatively install the Python interpreter after environment creation. For a list of installable Python versions, run `conda search "^python$"`.

```
conda install python  # latest available python version
conda install python=3.7  # specific python version
```

Comment: I'd just note that prior to Conda v4.4, Conda used to leave the **base** env on PATH, which is why previously people may have had experiences where not specifying `python` or `anaconda` explicitly still led to a Python on the PATH. But yeah, now the envs are totally isolated and hence `python` must be specified.

Comment: @merv thanks for the clarification. I've recently upgraded to the latest version of conda and got very confused when it didn't install anything in it. At this point my question is: what's the point of not installing even the base packages?

Comment: @wtfzambo I'd counter with: what's a "*base package*"? I liberally create environments and the intersection across all them is the empty set, hence I'd argue there is no such thing as a "base package" for all users. I think a big part of this is that Conda is a generalized package manager - not just Python - so envs can vary widely in what is installed. However, note that you are free to define your own custom default packages (see [docs](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#adding-default-packages-to-new-environments-automatically)).

Comment: @merv fair enough you got a point, with base packages I meant the ones that would get installed if I ran `conda create -n myenv python`. To rephrase, I was expecting `conda create -n myenv` behavior to default to the former command behavior.

Also because creating an virtual env without any python executable in it doesn't make much sense anyway, does it ?

Comment: @wtfzambo perhaps not if one is equating "*virtual env*" with "Python virtual env", but I think it is sensible for multi-lingual users. For example, I have many envs without `python` - some just have R, C++, an IDE (e.g., emacs), or some bioinformatics tools for particular pipelines. Also, note that Conda never installed `python` by default - rather it simply used to leave the **base** environment's `bin/` directory on `PATH` and that happened to include a Python interpreter, since `conda` itself is mainly written in Python.

Comment: @merv ahhh, I see my mistake now! Being a python dev only I used conda exclusively to do data-sciency stuff, and therefore didn't know / consider that it can be used as a package manager for many other things.

Answer (score 7):

You have to use this to get all of the Anaconda default packages:

```
conda create --name my_env anaconda
```

Otherwise, it doesn't install everything.

Comment: I'm actually using Miniconda, and don't want all the packages, but in my case it doesn't even create a copy of the python interpreter (i.e. python.exe)

Comment: Oh, sorry.  Couldn't actually see the screenshots at work.  What if you use Windows CMD instead of git-bash?

Comment: I used Anaconda Prompt and I got the same problem!

Comment: Worked like a charm. Using the above answer did not install all of the conda packages like pandas. However, your answer solved my problem using WIN10 CMD. Thank you.

Comment: Which version of python is installed when using the above code? The python version of the latest release of Anaconda from [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs/)?

Comment: I believe it is whatever version is the default for the Anaconda version you install.  E.g. if you install the Python 3.8 version it will be Python 3.8 or if you install the 3.7 version it will be 3.7.  You can also specify the version of Python by adding `python=[VERSION_NUM]` at the end of the above command.

Answer (score -1):

Everytime you set up a new venv with conda and want to have the python.exe file on the new venv you must run the following script:

```
conda install pip
```

Then just follow the indications and that's it!.