# How to Install a Package in PyCharm when project interpreter is set to conda, and the package is not provided/listed by conda?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, pydicom

I installed pycharm on my computer. I set the project interpreter to `acaconda3/bin/python` because that is the python3 interpreter I used on my computer before installing pycharm. I was able to install all packages I need using pycharm's package installer except for pydicom which is not provided by anaconda. However, pydicom, one of the packages I need for my project, is not provided by conda and hence does not show up in the list of available packages when I search.

How do I install this package that is not available with conda?

[image]

Comment: Haven't used conda, but doesn't pip work from anaconda command line?

Comment: I will guess that it does. How would I access anaconda command line from pycharm?

Comment: anaconda prompt should be there in your windows start menu, just search for it. install your package using pip, it will install to a default library, which should be accessible in pycharm .

Comment: I am using a mac.

Comment: Do I need to install it to the specific virtual environment created by pycharm? Or were you suggesting I install it in general on my machine?

Comment: I just tried to switch to the virtualenvironment created by pycharm by doing `source activate virtualenvname` but that did not help.

Comment: Open Anaconda Prompt in your environment, and run

`conda install -c conda-forge pydicom ` or

`conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken pydicom`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using (Ana)conda within PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390961/using-anaconda-within-pycharm)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Open Anaconda navigator

[image]

- Open environment from side tab
- Open your environment which you created or choose the default( seems
  in this case)
- Choose `Open in terminal`
- Run pip command here.

---

OR run pip by going to directory `anaconda3/Scripts` directory

---

Since `pydicom` is supported by `conda-forge` channel it wont show up on Pycharm unless you add that channel to `conda` environment channels manually.

Run below command for the environment

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

[image]

Then it should show up in Pycharm.

[image]

Once channel added you can run below command within environment

```
conda install pydicom
```

**Reference:**

- [pydicom.github](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/getting_started.html#installing)
- [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/)
- [so/using-anaconda-within-pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390961/using-anaconda-within-pycharm?rq=1)

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without using anaconda navigator which I cannot access on a Mac?

Comment: Updated answer .and why can't you just install navigator for Mac https://anaconda.org/anaconda/anaconda-navigator ?

Comment: Sounds like a lot of manual boilerplate work for a language for automation

Answer (score 4):

Using PyCharm 2020.2 I can do this without going to the terminal or Anaconda.

Go to "Settings->Project->Python Interpreter" (same place as VictorLegros went, but the UI is different now: note the + button at the bottom of the list of packages)

Hit the + button, search for your package in the new dialog and then click "Install Package"

[image]

I double checked in the Anaconda UI afterward, and - after click on Update Index.. and waiting a bit (not 100% sure that was necessary, but I didn't see it at first)  - I can now see the package "scikit-learn" that installed via PyCharm.

[image]

(Note: I'm not *using* Anaconda to do anything but verify: the search and installation was all in PyCharm)

Comment: In this way it only shows conda packages

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and I figured out that from the python interpreter dialogue I had to click the green circular Conda icon to disable "Use Conda Package Manager" (above the list of packages).  Then when I clicked to add a package, I found all the packages I needed, which I presume were installed with pip.

I was also able to install packages that Conda needed to handle like psycopg2.    Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh well, thanks for giving this detailed instruction. It works for me!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's identical on the Mac, but for Win 10 Pycharm, you can access the Terminal from:

View > Tool Windows > Terminal (Alt+F12)

[image: Pycharm Terminal Menu Item]

From there, make sure the correct conda environment is active through:

```
conda activate <your_env>
```

Then, you can install a package as one normally would typing in the command line, e.g.

```
conda install -c conda-forge <some_thing>
```

[image: PyCharm Terminal View]

The exact command changes if you're using pip or some other manager or repository location, but it's helpful to do it this way if you want to stay in the IDE.

Also, you can verify the package in present in File > Settings > Project: ... > Python Interpreter

You should see your manually added package listed here, even though you didn't install it through the GUI.

[image: PyCharm Installed Packages]