# How to install mpl_finance packages into environment on Anaconda?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, mplfinance

How to install the `mpl_finance` package into the environment path on Anaconda?

I tried `pip install mpl_finance` but I still can't find the package on Anaconda, where did it go? I am pretty fresh in Python.

Comment: did you try `conda install mpl_finance` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using (Ana)conda within PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390961/using-anaconda-within-pycharm)

Comment: @AlbinPaul, I tried, I got this "PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:"

Comment: @Georgy, thanks Georgy.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to anaconda prompt
2. Select your environment
3. Run `pip install mpl_finance`

In your code, change `matplotlib.finance`  to `mpl_finance`

regards

Comment: mpl_finance is deprecated

Answer (score 4):

The mpl-finance (aka mpl_finance) package is deprecated. As of December 2019 there is a new version of matplotlib finance, with documentation. https://pypi.org/project/mplfinance/

---

Install with:

`pip install --upgrade mplfinance`

or

`conda install -c conda-forge mplfinance`

---

The new package name does NOT have the dash- or underscore_

It is now `mplfinance` (*not* `mpl-finance`, nor `mpl_finance`).

Comment: Side question: how do you get Anaconda to add a new module to their installation catalog?

Comment: There is not yet a `conda` package for the new `mplfinance`.  (Soon hopefully).  In the meantime, if you use the `pip` that is within your conda environment, you can `pip install mplfinance` individually to each conda environment, and **it will work** in that conda environment, but it will **not** be conda managed, so the conda catalog will not display it as installed.

Comment: I did that, but I want to tell Anaconda to speed up adding it. I also want them to be quicker with pandas, they limit me to 0.25 currently, 2-3 versions behind for such a key package. There seem to be ways around Anaconda dependencies for that too  but too complicated (for me).

Comment: @DISC-O  Not 100% sure, but as I understand things, it's up to each package maintainer to create a conda install-package.  Therefore it's up to pandas maintainers to make a more recent version for conda, and it is up to me (as maintainer of mplfinance) to make mplfinance available for conda.  I hope to do that in another two months (sooner if someone offers to help). These are generally volunteer projects that progress as people have time to work on them.  Regarding pandas you can contact their maintainers possibly through Github.  All the best.

Comment: I have added an issue to create a conda install: https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/62  ... not sure when we'll get to it, but its there now so we don't forget.

Answer (score 1):

`conda install -c conda-forge mplfinance`