# "No module named dgl" but the module works

Tags: python, pycharm

When I type the line below into my PyCharm editor, it says "No module named dgl". If I click install, it gives me an error. I use an Anaconda environment with dgl installed for my configuration. The code calling dlg.DGLGraph() works as it should.

```
import dgl
g = dgl.DGLGraph()
```

The only real problem that I am having with it (I can live with my code constantly showing me a warning), is that the autocompletion doesn't work on my PyCharm editor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using (Ana)conda within PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390961/using-anaconda-within-pycharm)

Comment: does your code completion works? If not then check power save mood and turn it off.

Comment: code compiles correctly @NaSirHuSSaiN

Comment: @MariusKuzm i am asking about code completion not compilation.

Comment: Power save mode is off. Code completion works with every module except the dgl, i assume thats because it thinks its not installed @NaSirHuSSaiN

Comment: yeah. I think soo

Answer (score 0):

This problem is that you first install dgl, after this you install pytorch.
The correct method for install dgl is that you should first install pytorch, then install dgl. because pytorch is a dependency of dgl.