# Cannot import scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, anaconda

Beginner here, please be gentle! I’m receiving an error that reads

> ImportError: No module named sklearn when using pycharm.

I’m trying to import `matplotlib`, `numpy`, and `sklearn`. I’ve downloaded `scikit_learn`. I’ve also downloaded `anaconda`.

I have “two” pythons. Looks like this…

1. `MacHD/Library/Frameworks/python.framework/versions/3.4/site-packages/sklearn`
2. `MacHD/Library/Python/2.7/` ... in here is `pip` and `scikit_learn`

The strange thing is that `matplotlib` and `numpy` work but not `sklearn`. How can I figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Where are `matplotlib` and `numpy`? You can find out like this: `import numpy` then `print numpy.__file__`.

Comment: numpy…
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/numpy/__init__.pyc


matplotlib…
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/__init__.pyc

Comment: Type ```which python``` to see which python is being used. Also anaconda should be its own python....

Comment: It's using anaconda. I get this... //anaconda/bin/python @J-S

Comment: `which python` only works in terminal btw, not in pycharm. I dont know if that helps. @J-S

Comment: Type `python --version` in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The `MacHD/Library/Frameworks/python.framework/versions/3.4/site-packages/sklearn` is for Python 3.4 (note the `3.4` in the path) and the `MacHD/Library/Python/2.7/` is for Python 2.7. The packages for each are independent of each other.

Comment: The problem looks like it's between `pycharm` and `anaconda`. The project interpreter in `pycharm` is set to 2.7.10 (/anaconda/bin/python.app), which should be the right one. Import error: No module named sklearn still comes up. The answer on this link is the closest to solving my problem so far (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931049/getting-pycharm-to-recognize-anacondas-scipy). I've followed all the instructions except their is no prompt for  "prompt you to install setup_tools and pip for that interpreter"